# How can I search a pattern and extract the value behind it

Tags: python-3.x

I am a newbee in python. I am trying to pull data (`XXXX`) out from a text with a pattern `PDB:XXXX`. The `XXXX` varies, but it is exactly what I want.

Since the data all contain `PDB:`, I use `re.findall()` to search and get this pattern. But this only gave me a list of `PDB:`. How can I get it to include the `XXXX`???

this is my code:

```
text = 'blah...........
        PDB:AAAA
        blah...........
        blah...........
        PDB:BBBB'
```

etc.

```
r = re.findall("PDB:",text)
```

and the output gave me:

```
['PDB:', 'PDB:']
```

My desired output should be something like

```
['AAAA', 'BBBB']
```

Comment: Is XXXX always 4 characters exactly?

Comment: Yes, four characters, but not the same characters tho

Comment: try `re.findall(r'PDB:....', str)`  `.` matches any character.  Check out regexr.com, it is a really great resource for trying out and learning about regexes

Comment: @Ĵošħ The pattern could also be `r'PDB:.{4}'`, which is easier to read

Comment: @wjandrea good call! forgot about that

Comment: Thank you so much. That really helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `"""` to quote multi-line strings in Python. Also, to get a specific subset of the matched pattern, you need to use capture groups (the parentheses in my regular expression below).

```
import re

text = """blah...........
        PDB:AAAA
        blah...........
        blah...........
        PDB:BBBB"""

results = re.findall(r"PDB:(.*)", text)

print results #['AAAA', 'BBBB']
```

Comment: This will take every character after the `:` up to the newline character. OP stated the length of these is fixed, though.